# Programmatically remove registered instance from Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Is there a way to remove a registered instance from the Eureka Server without using REST operations? Which is the data structure that contains all the applications?

(It's clear that I want to remove them writing code in the Eureka Server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are after is available via the [`InstanceRegistry`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/InstanceRegistry.java), which is itself just an extension of the Netflix Eureka classes ([`PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl`](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/registry/PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.java), and [`AbstractInstanceRegistry`](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/registry/AbstractInstanceRegistry.java)).

Specifically, the `AbstractInstanceRegistry#cancel(String,String,boolean)` method should remove applications from the registry.

The Javadoc for this method states:

```
/**
 * Cancels the registration of an instance.
 *
 * <p>
 * This is normally invoked by a client when it shuts down informing the
 * server to remove the instance from traffic.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param appName the application name of the application.
 * @param id the unique identifier of the instance.
 * @param isReplication true if this is a replication event from other nodes, false
 *                      otherwise.
 * @return true if the instance was removed from the {@link AbstractInstanceRegistry} successfully, false otherwise.
 */
```

This is how you would achieve this from the Eureka server itself.